# Importing multiple csv files to mysql tables

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

**UPDATE**

The second after I posted this question, thanks to the syntax highlighting of the resulting queries I saw what went wrong: the `$pl` string didn't open with a closing back tick. Now I changed it to:

```
$pk = ',`%1$sUSER`,`%1$sTYPE`,`%1$sCODE`,`%1$sVALUE`,`%1$s';//WRONG
$pk = '`,`%1$sUSER`,`%1$sTYPE`,`%1$sCODE`,`%1$sVALUE`,`%1$s';//OK
```

However, this poses a new question: why didn't the PDO object spew errors back at me for this? executing the query manually surely would return an error saying there is no field called `fld2_AGE,`, with a comma at the end. Why didn't I get any errors? any Ideas?

PS: any idea's how to upvote SO's syntax highlighting for solving my problem? :-)

I'm leaving the original question as a reference/example, though it doesn't need solving anymore

---

Ok, I've been using a script I wrote a while back to import generate several csv files from a huge file, to quickly import the data into several mysql tables. This script has worked failry well in the past (I think) up until I wrote a second script, in which I accidentally truncated my tables (stupid, I know). 'No biggie' I thought, as I had the the script, it would be a matter of seconds to restore my data. Unfortunately, I found that now, only one file is being imported, and no errors are showing. Below I have pasted the entire db section of the script. When I execute this code, all I get is the output `files imported successfully`, which is the very last line of code...

I know it's a failry large block of code, with a lot of string format printing, which doesn't improve readability, so I've also provided the resulting query strings below. As far as I can tell, they look well formatted, as do the files (I checked). Can anyone tell where else I'm supposed to look for errors? It would be a great help... Thanks!

```
<?php
$files = array_fill_keys(array('filename1','filename2','filename3','filename4'),'');
//$files === array of handles fputcsv($files['filename1'],array('values','from','other','files'),';');
$tbls = array_combine($files,array('tblname1','tblname2','tblname3','tblname4'));
$path = dirname(__FILE__)'/';
$qf = 'LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE \'%s%s.csv\' INTO TABLE my_db.tbl_prefix_%s FIELDS TERMINATED BY \';\' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY \'"\' LINES TERMINATED BY \'\n\'';
$pref = array_combine($files,array('fld1_','fld2_','fld3_','fld3_'));
$pkA = ' (`%1$sNAME`,`%1$sAGE';
$pk = '`,`%1$sUSER`,`%1$sTYPE`,`%1$sCODE`,`%1$sVALUE`,`%1$s';
try
{
    $db = new PDO('mysql:host=mysqlhostn','user','pass');
    foreach($files as $f)
    {
        $db->beginTransaction();
        $db->exec(sprintf('TRUNCATE TABLE my_db.tbl_prefix_%s',$tbls[$f]));
        $db->commit();
    }
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
    if ($db)
    {
        $db->rollBack();
        $db = null;
    }
    die('DB connection/truncate failed: '.$e->getMessage()."\n");
}
try
{
    while($f = array_shift($files))
    {
        $db->beginTransaction();
        $q = sprintf($qf,$path,$f,$tbls[$f]).sprintf($pkA.($f !== 'agent' ? $pk : ''),$pref[$f]);
        switch($f)
        {
            case 'filename3':
                $q .= 'tbl3_specific_field';
            break;
            case 'filename2':
                $q .= sprintf('tbl2_specific_field`,`%1$tbl2_specific_field2',$pref[$f]);
            break;
            case 'filename4':
                $q .= sprintf('tbl4_specific_field`,`%1$tbl4_specific_field2`,`%1$tbl4_specific_field3`,`%1$tbl4_specific_field4',$pref[$f]);
            break;
        }
        $stmt = $db->prepare($q.'`)');
        $stmt->execute();
        $db->commit();
    }
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
    $db->rollBack();
    $e = 'CSV import Failed: '.$e->getMessage();
    $db=null;
    die($e."\n");
}
$db = null;
exit('files imported successfully'."\n");
?>
```

generated Queries - execution output:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE my_db.tbl_prefix_tblname1
TRUNCATE TABLE my_db.tbl_prefix_tblname2
TRUNCATE TABLE my_db.tbl_prefix_tblname3
TRUNCATE TABLE my_db.tbl_prefix_tblname4

LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/local/path/to/files/filename1.csv' INTO TABLE my_db.tbl_prefix_tblname1 FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' (`fld1_NAME`,`fld1_AGE`)
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/local/path/to/files/filename2.csv' INTO TABLE my_db.tbl_prefix_tblname2 FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' (`fld2_NAME`,`fld2_AGE,`fld2_USER`,`fld2_TYPE`,`fld2_CODE`,`fld2_VALUE`,`fld2_tbl2_specific_field`,`fld2_tbl2_specific_field2`)
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/local/path/to/files/filename3.csv' INTO TABLE my_db.tbl_prefix_tblname3 FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' (`fld3_NAME`,`fld3_AGE,`fld3_USER`,`fld3_TYPE`,`fld3_CODE`,`fld3_VALUE`,`fld3_tbl3_specific_field`)
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/local/path/to/files/filename4.csv' INTO TABLE my_db.tbl_prefix_tblname4 FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' (`fld4_NAME`,`fld4_AGE,`fld4_USER`,`fld4_TYPE`,`fld4_CODE`,`fld4_VALUE`,`fld4_tbl4_specific_field`,`fld4_tbl4_specific_field2`,`fld4_tbl4_specific_field3`,`fld4_tbl4_specific_field4`)
```

> csv imported successfully

File1 is getting imported as I need it to be, an example of the first file:

> 11;9

While the actual content of file2 (which isn't getting imported) looks like this:

> 11;9;25;5;FOOBAR;Z;333;321;123

Both first fields contain the same data, as they should, both tables have the same field definitions, same storage engine (InnoDB), collation (UTF-8)... I have no idea what's causing the problem, so any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> why didn't the PDO object spew errors back at me for this?

Because MySQL executed your query without any errors. Only because you've written the wrong query this must not mean that the query is that wrong that MySQL won't accept it.

Whenever you generate SQL queries programmatically, verify (by debugging or even better unit-tests), that the query has been created right for what you want to do.

If you want to get an exception each time an error occurs, enable that:

```
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

Comment: If I attempt to execute the malformed query, I do get a 1064 back

Comment: So you get an error back, you just don't check it. You might want to enable exceptions for each error, but you need to configure PDO for that. See as well [Possible PDOException Errors (MySQL 5)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/744656/possible-pdoexception-errors-mysql-5) and especially [Why PDO Exception Error Not Caught?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8180064/367456)

Comment: `$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` added this right after creating my connection. Thanks for the tip! I did test the generated queries, but I think I might have deleted that character by accident, using vim, the difference between `d4 ` and `d5 ` can be huge :-)

Comment: Better than manual tests are automattic ones. Especially if you let run your code on large amounts of data.