# import txt/csv data into database according to database table header

Tags: php, mysql, csv, import, header

My tex/csv file has 3 columns `first_name`, `last_name` and `address`  but my database table has two columns `first_name` and `last_name`.  I wish to have a function that even there are many columns in `csv` that not exist in the table it still can just pick the right column and insert into table.
Some one advise me using php `mysql_fetch_field`. I am trying `mysql_fetch_field` and I can collect my database table columns name but I can't insert data according to table header.

```
     set_time_limit(0);

    include "connection.php"; //Connect to Database


    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    // Gel table current column name

    $query = "select * from month";
    $result=mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());

    $i = 0;
    while ($i < mysql_num_fields($result)) {
        $meta = mysql_fetch_field($result, $i);

        $a=$meta->name;

        $i++;
    }

    //Upload File

    if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'])) {
            echo "<h1>" . "File ". $_FILES['filename']['name'] ." uploaded successfully." . "</h1>";
            echo "<h2>Displaying contents:</h2>";
            readfile($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name']);
        }

        //Import uploaded file to Database
        $handle = fopen($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'], "r");

            $header = fgetcsv($handle);


        while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
            $import="INSERT into month($header[0],$header[1]) values('$data[0]','$data[1]')";

            mysql_query($import) or die(mysql_error());
        }

        fclose($handle);

        echo "Import done";

    }
```

Comment: Don't use `mysql_*` as it's going to be deprecated, switch to `PDO` or `mysqli_*`. Also [here's](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10478861/importing-multiple-csv-files-to-mysql-tables) an example of `LOAD LOCAL INFILE` using PDO that might be useful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I get what you need but I think you should use `MySQL Load Data Infile` to load that `CSV` like this:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'your_file.csv'
INTO TABLE your_table
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
(field1, field2, field3)
```

That's how I work with `CSV` and it does the job pretty well.

Check this [link](http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/2345/import_csv_file_directly_into_mysql/).

Answer (score 0):

You can use MySQL's [`LOAD DATA INFILE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/load-data.html) command.  As documented in the manual:

> You can also discard an input value by assigning it to a user variable and not assigning the variable to a table column:
>
> ```
> LOAD DATA INFILE 'file.txt'
>   INTO TABLE t1
>   (column1, @dummy, column2, @dummy, column3);
> ```

Therefore, in your case:

```sql
LOAD DATA INFILE '/path/to/file' INTO TABLE month
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"'
  IGNORE 1 LINES
  (first_name, last_name, @dummy);
```