# Set timestamp on insert when loading CSV

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a `Timestamp` field that is defined to be automatically updated with the `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` value.
It works fine when I fire a query, but when I import a csv (which I'm forced to do since one of the fields is longtext) , the update does not work.

I have tried to:

1. Give timestamp column as `now()` function in csv
2. Manually enter timestamp like `2013-08-08` in the csv

Both the approaches do not work

Comment: what error You are getting?

Comment: We can't help unless you show your code? How are you inserting the csv? are you using phpMyAdmin, some third party code or did you write a one-off import script? what does the CSV look like? show the `CREATE TABLE` query, too, for good mesure. Does the field that should contain the timestamp have a default value?

Comment: Please, if you don't like the answer you got the first time asking a question, either _edit_ the question, provide more info, or ask for more feedback, but don't blindly post the same question again. I've voted to close for that reason. I have provided a detailed answer, though... so please: respect my effort and at least read it, try it and provide me with feedback, too

Comment: I am importing csv file through phpmyadmin and not by any code

Comment: @SanjayRathod: phpMyAdmin can _show_ you the query it generated for you. Look into that query and edit it using one or more suggestions I made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I gather, after updating your question, is that you're actually *updating* rows using a CSV, and expect the `ON UPDATE` clause to set the value of your timestamp field to be updated.
Sadly, when loading a CSV into a database you're not updating, but *inserting* data, and overwriting existing records. At least, when using a `LOCAL INFILE`, if the `INFILE` isn't local, the query will produce an error, if it's a local file, these errors (duplicates) will produce warnings and the operation will continue.

If this isn't the case for you, perhaps consider [following one of the examples on the doc pages](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html):

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'your.csv'
   INTO TABLE tbl
      (field_name1, field_name2, field_name3)
   SET updated = NOW()
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
       OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY ('\n');
```

Just in case you can't/won't/forget to add additional information, loading a csv int a MySQL table is quite easy:

```
LOAD DATA
   LOCAL INFILE '/path/to/file/filename1.csv'
INTO TABLE db.tbl
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
    OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
(`field_name1`,`field_name2`,`field_name3`)
```

If you create a table along the lines of:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl(
   id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, -- since your previous question mentioned auto-increment
   field_name1 VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, -- normal fields
   field_name2 INTEGER(11) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
   field_name3 VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    -- when not specified, this field will receive current_timestamp as value:
   inserted TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
   -- if row is updated, this field will hold the timestamp of update-time
   updated TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
                              ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
)ENGINE = INNODB
 CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

This query is untested, so please be careful with it, it's just to give a general idea of what you need to do to get the insert timestamp in there.
This example table will work like so:

```
> INSERT INTO tbl (field_name1, field_name2) VALUES ('foobar', 123);
> SELECT FROM tbl WHERE field_name1 = 'foobar' AND field_name2 = 123;
```

This will show:

```
+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
|          id         |     field_name1     |     field_name2     |     field_name3     |       inserted      |       updated       |
+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
|           1         |        foobar       |         123         |                     | 2013-08-07 00:00:00 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |
+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

As you can see, because we didn't explicitly insert a value into the last three fields, MySQL used their `DEFAULT` values. For `field_name3`, an empty string was used, for `inserted`, the default was `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`, for `updated` the default value was `0` which, because the field-type is `TIMESTAMP` is represented by the value `0000-00-00 00:00:00`. If you were to run the following query next:

```
UPDATE tbl
   SET field_name3 = 'an update'
WHERE field_name1 = 'foobar'
  AND field_name2 = 123
  AND id          = 1;
```

The row would look like this:

```
+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
|          id         |     field_name1     |     field_name2     |     field_name3     |       inserted      |       updated       |
+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
|           1         |        foobar       |         123         |      an update      | 2013-08-07 00:00:00 | 2013-08-07 00:00:20 |
+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

that's all. Some basics can be found [here, on mysqltutorial.org](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-timestamp.aspx), but best keep [the official manual ready](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/index.html). It's not bad once you get used to it.
Perhaps [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10478861/importing-multiple-csv-files-to-mysql-tables) might be worth a quick peek, too.